# Sub panel neutral and ground not bonded so why continuity between them?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have a 125A GE PowerMark Gold Load Center "subpanel" at my detached garage. Subpanel has 2 hots, one neutral with no "connected" ground between panels. The subpanel ground bus bar is tied to a local 8ft subterranean 5/8" grounding rod. 50A branch breaker at main feeding 6/3 wire about 100ft tied directly to the subpanel inlets (H/H/N). Per NEC, the neutral and ground in the subpanel are not bonded (i did not screw in the green bonding screw that came with the panel).

[image: GE Load Center Image]

All the outlets including GFCIs all work correctly. When I test panel buses with my meter in the garage I have 120v between neutral and each hot and have 120v between ground and each hot. Sounds good right? Then why do I have continuity between neutral bus bar and ground bar also between neutral bus bar and panel box itself?!? I thought that if I don't insert the screw, then neutral should be "separate" from ground and panel metal box? Or is this normal?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for quick reply. I used my meter leads to touch the neutral bus and ground bus  . .. "beep" also using leads to touch neutral bus and metal box  .. . "beep" and ground and metal box. . . "beep"  With no ties between bars and no bonding screw, how can they connect?

Comment: this is my first post and unsure how to upload a photo. i took a photo on inside of subpanel and uploaded to Drop box here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/djbuhve2edbm1g5/subpanel.jpg?dl=0. Also what is meant exactly by wiring method? maybe the picture will reveal that. Note ground conductor inside 6/3 romex is cut off at both ends- not used). Also note the boding screw is not inserted on left in neutral bus bar. The three ground wires are for those three branch circuits

Comment: Sean S if you totally disconnect the white neutral and measure to the ground it will still be connected everything is fine don’t try and change things.  See my answer isolation of the neutral bus is to prevent a parallel grounding path and stop objectionable current from using the grounding conductor as a neutral. If not isolated this would happen but they go to the same place in the main so there is continuity.

Comment: @SeanS -- why on earth is that grounding conductor not used!? And is that UF in the conduit, or NM!?

Comment: @j... please review a feeder in the code that is fed by a main panel. In fact I will make it easy look at exhibit 250.42 or 250.41 see those pictures that connect the green grounding conductor to the neutral buss? This is required in the main, now check out 250.45, 250.46  what is common in all these pictures ? Something call a main bonding jumper.

Comment: If the op doesn’t have a conductive path via conduit or wire it is not wired to code it could be a common writer pipe but earth will not provide even close to single digit resistance readings much less below 1.  I finally got tired on people downvoting and not providing an upvote for an accurate code answer and will continue to point outlandish statements.

Comment: @EdBeal No, it isn't wired to code.  The picture they posted and the description they gave is enough to figure that out.  The feeder conduit is plastic and the ground wire is cut at both ends.  In addition to not being to code, though, (because of the missing ground) there appears to be a connection between the neutral and the ground rod ground in the sub from all the information OP has given.  I'd like them to confirm with some measurements, but OP does not yet have the right answer here.  They should absolutely be reading 10s or 100s of ohms between neutral and rod-ground and they're not.

Comment: OP I am concerned about several things about the installation, and would much rather see photos of the panel, cable entry, and various neutral and ground bars.  I am concerned perhaps the N-G bond was not pulled.  And I want to see if that ground wire in the feeder is recoverable; deleting that was sheer negligence.

Comment: I finely got that photo to open on my phone the ground wire appears to be touching the case not sure why it was cut but it can be attached to the box and be code compliant. Green screw self forming not tapping that wire would be the only way to get that low of a reading or through a pipe that is grounded water even lake water or water with salt will not provide 10 ohms through just a grounding rod and dirt.

Comment: @SeanS -- is that a NM or a UF cable in the conduit entering the panel with the feeder inside it, and is that conduit continuous back to the main panel?

Comment: Yes NM in conduit, entire distance. the 6/3 ground is 12wa wire, not 6, cut and non-terminated at both ends (panels).When i had it connected, we had about 2A o 3A  flowing back over it, the rest was on the neutral. We disconnected the ground at both ends and all the (8A) current flowed back over neutral. We researched for a non-detached building, tying the ground panel to panel is required (6Ga for this 50A circuit).  Fo detached, it was to be eliminated and the ground was to be tied to a dedicated ground rod at the subpanel.

Comment: All of my assumption could be wrong, This is my first subpanel installation.I could read the ohms again and post results? Going to test house outlets anyway with circuit analyzer. FWIW, I did have an electrician come by and he said everything looked good but was scratching his head about the continuity.

Comment: “For detached, it was to be eliminated and the ground was to be tied to a dedicated ground rod at the subpanel” *Code never said that... since like 1990, you need both.*

Comment: So the electrician never showed up. But this is what I found. There is a dual pole 30A (240V) branch ckt breaker in my subpanel. Thanks to @J - In isolating and troubleshooting I discovered that it is causing this continuity and probably the reason for the current flow back over the panel-to-panel ground connection (which I cut and have not hooked back up yet). When i remove the 30A-240v (L6-R30) receptacle from metal the outlet box, the continuity N-G at the subpanel disappears.

Comment: If i check continuity on the standalone receptacle itself (no wires connected), the neutral has continuity with the metal mounting "ears" of the receptacle. Since this receptacle has no ground screw, the HTTN ground wire is screwed down to the metal receptacle box and the other end to the grounding bus in the subpanel. There is the "link" from neutral to the subpanel ground bus. 

So I am sure something is violated here. Maybe the receptacle itself or maybe I cannot have a 240V breaker in the subpanel? Or maybe i should use a plastic outlet box?

Comment: Or maybe . . .the 30A 240v outlet is H-H-G, not H-H-N? The two hots go to the breaker (as they are now) and the other 3rd wire goes to ground bus, not Neutral bus in subpanel?

Comment: @SeanS Hold on... are you sure that's an L6-30R or any of the NEMA 6 family receps?  **Those don't have neutral**.  That third pin is safety ground.  Not only that, but the ground screw/lug/terminal is internally connected to the receptacle's yoke, as you are measuring.  Yes, problem found, I'd say!  If you want a receptacle that is H-H-N, **you don't**. You don't want a receptacle that is H-H-N. They're dangerous, and they've been outlawed since '96.  Use NEMA 14, which is H-H-N-G.

Comment: Yep thanks @Harper for clarifying, that was it! I moved that third wire from the N-busto the ground bus in the SP and "continuity" issue resolved. Can i use green tape for the 10white wire used or do i have to replace with TNNH 10Green?

Comment: Also per your previous comments, I was able to get the long ground feed into each panel and terminate to the ground bus on both sides (literally 10 minutes ago). I put load on the 30A/240 ckt and measured current in and out using ammeter. It's balanced on hot and neutral return, less than .2A on ground wire back to panel!

Comment: As to the receptacle, its a standard:30 Amp 250-Volt Flush Mounting Grounding Locking Outlet, Black from Home Depot. L6-R30

Comment: Looks like i need a 14? We use those on various jobs and have cables for generators mostly (I also used that for my inlet transfer switch box at main panel two weeks ago). Note: We had two L6-30R outlets installed in my garage a couple of years ago by a commercial electrician/friend. It was specifically for APC UPS. This one I installed is designed for same application. I didn't know those receptacles (L6-30R) were outlawed.

Comment: @SeanS -- NEMA 6/L6 is fine and dandy provided it's wired correctly (H-H-G).  It's the NEMA 10 (nominally H-H-N) that's the usual culprit in being old and scary, but in your case, a prior installer managed to hide a wolf (NEMA 10) in sheep's clothing (NEMA L6).

Comment: L6-30R is fine if you don't use the ground pin for neutral.  NEMA 6 is legal... it's NEMA 10 that's outlawed.   You cannot re-mark wires #6 or smaller unless you are remarking a neutral to a hot.  Use the ground wire that must surely be in the cable and just cap off the neutral and push it into the back of the box.  Never cut off or destroy a wire... you might need it someday!

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually need neutral.  Then NEMA 6 is fine, and you can just cap the wire off and tuck it into the back of the box.  Insulate it like a hot wire, neutral can be hot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Edit: Found it!  It's a miswired NEMA 6 recep.

NEMA 6 family receptacles provide Hot, Hot **and ground**.   Someone had miswired a NEMA 6 recep by connecting a neutral wire to the recep's ground lug.

The ground screw and metal chassis of the socket are internally connected, just like any other ground screw on any other receptacle or switch.

One should never wire a neutral wire to a NEMA 6.  That violates a lot of stuff, but also 110.3(B) requiring you follow instructions and labeling.

There's no such thing as a receptacle that provides hot-hot-neutral.  That is an illegal connection -- anything big enough to need 30A also needs a ground wire.  The only options are NEMA 6, or NEMA 14 (hot-hot-**neutral-ground** - 4 pins in total).

If someone has a legacy appliance that needs hot-hot-neutral, then that needs to be wired up NEMA 14. If it's a range or dryer, it will have a "bootleg jumper" internally typing neutral to ground; that must be removed, as per its instructions.

### Current on the ground wire

This is a very serious matter that HAS to be found.

To start with, we need to know that the panel is isolating the neutral and ground bars.  Lift all your neutrals including the feeder (remove them from the bar) and then use a plain ohmmeter to check between the neutral bar and the ground bar. That must be infinity ohms.  If not that's a problem with the panel config, like a N-G bonding screw that you missed.

Now with all the breakers off, reconnect branch circuits neutrals one at a time, and check again. Should still be infinity ohms.  If adding a branch circuit causes it to go to low resistance, that branch has a ground fault (possibly neutral-ground).  Chase that down.

I suspect you'll find something here.   That is the likeliest explanation for current on ground.

Now I have an alternative explanation.  It's possible your wiring is correct. Suppose your neighbor has a lost neutral.  Neutral will get back to the transformer via their neutral-ground bond, their ground rods, dirt, your garage's ground rods, your feeder ground wire, your main panel's neutral-ground bond and your neutral back to the transformer you share.  This current isn't yours in this case.  Your neighbor has the problem.

### Neutral bar

OK so that's a GE panel, it looks like it has 14 real *spaces*, 10 of which allow thin breakers (note croses on buses) so max 24 circuits.

I see a left-side neutral bar with about 24 usable screws.  That would seem to suffice, so I'm unclear on the purpose of the right side bar.  **The [documentation](https://library.industrialsolutions.abb.com/publibrary/checkout/DEH-41267?TNR=Installation%20and%20Instruction%7CDEH-41267%7CPDF&filename=DEH-41267.pdf) describes it as a "grounding bar"**, which settles the matter. It has its own chassis-grounding screw.  So it appears this bar is unfit to be a neutral bar (a high-current path does not exist between it and the neutral lugs) and GE has simply insulated the ground bar for no apparent reason.  While also providing an auxiliary location for an additional TGL2 grounding bar kit. Together they would provide 24 grounds, but that's usually not an issue since you're allowed to double-tap or triple-tap grounds.

This panel is definitely a puzzle. I can see why you asked.

### Broken off ground

The broken off ground wire is a serious defect.  You MUST have both proper grounding rods, AND a wired ground wire back to the main panel.  That's mandatory.

This installation appears to be cable *in* conduit, which has "amateur hour" written all over it.  If the conduit is continuous, the cable can be yanked out, and replaced with individual wires with an intact ground wire.  Fair chance the installation is improper *anyway*; that's either NM cable (illegal outside) or UF cable (illegal in 1.5" conduit; requires 2" conduit); so that would need to be done.  This would be legal if it was round SE cable.

The quickest way to restore the ground wire is to pull the cable back enough to cut the conduit and fit a steel junction box immediately above the panel with an EMT nipple connecting it to the panel. The steel/EMT will be a continuous ground. It's the quickest way of making the panel "taller" so the ground wire can reach an appropriate land (in the new box).  You can't use the 1" stub of ground wire as it is; it needs to come 6" into the box to be Code.

Comment: The other possibility is that somewhere in the branch circuitry there is a neutral/ground connection.  I think OP should disconnect all wires from the panel and check that the ground and neutral bars are isolated, then progressively add circuits back onto the busses, checking isolation at each point.  Something is shorting ground and neutral at or past the sub.  Either that or OP's ground rod has a buried line going all the way back to the house or something crazy like that.

Comment: Re: Broken off ground: This is a subpanel in a detached building and so we followed NEC for a separate grounding rod. With the ground conductor connected panel to panel, there is return current ~3.2A flowing back over it, big no-no. Also, with that panel to panel ground tied like you mention, it then connects the isolated subpanel ground to the bonded ground, another no-no.

Comment: And true on the "Amateur Hour" observation. I am an IT guy, not an electrician. To be honest, I just watched some you tube videos and installed this entire thing "hot". Crazy of course. I wouldn't do that again. Anyway yes it was difficult getting that 6/3 Romex (NM) into 100+ feet of flex and conduit.

Comment: @SeanS Sorry, it never occurred to me the conduit job was your work.  Well, now you know; you can pull THHN.   Unfortunately, you'll have to do it again because of the NM-outdoors or UF-too-big problem... or if SE, use one of the other remedies I discussed.

Comment: @SeanS How did you measure that 3.2A?  Between ground from the panel and the ground rod? With nothing else going on? That does seem like an awful lot, but it would depend on what you've measured.

Comment: Yikes, ok well it will be easier to pull THHN if I have to redo.  I am guessing i can pull the Romex apart and just keep those loose wires in the 100' flex/conduit? From panel it goes NM to under the house, then flex ~80 feet tied to subfloor, then thru garage, still same flex, then NM conduit underground for 15' to sub. For measurement, I used a clampmeter around Hot leg coming into the sub and around the Neutral and the 12ga ground. I had 8.1 on hot leg, 6.2 on Neutral and ~1.7 on ground 12ga the first time i measured. it varied slightly from there.

Comment: @SeanS -- you'll have to pull the NM out *entirely* and pull actual THHNs through the conduit (you'll be very thankful once you get the NM out of there!).  Also, are you saying that the conduit isn't continuous all the way back to the panel?

Comment: @SeanS Well it sounds like we've got more work to do.  The leakage on ground HAS to be found. I added some stuff to the front of my answer.

Comment: Yes @3Phase on conduit, its panel to NM to flex to NM to panel. I also @J request shut the load off to box, pulled all three breakers, pulled neutrals from sp bus, and grong rod tie as well as grounds off ground bar. Tested resistance on neutral to ground and got ~300Ohms. also no continuity between neutral and ground or neutral and box, both gone. I hooked it all back up the way it was, same as before condition but the loads are working as they were so i left it for now. I asked a good electrician to come out and take a look Monday. Will see what he finds. Very reputable dude.

Comment: The punch-list so far is to  . . . at least re-pull as THHN and terminate the ground box-to-box. Maybe EMT for panel box termination to flex so I have metal the entire path. The path it takes now is main panel outside house to under house to across garage ceiling to underground ~10ft to  Shed to subpanel

Comment: @SeanS 300 ohms is sensible for neutral to the ground rod.  Something in your garage branch wiring is shorting neutral and ground, it would seem.

Comment: @SeanS Also, if it's NM to flex (assuming you mean teck table or AC armoured flex, etc) and the flex is underground then you may not need to change the NM.  As long as the NM is only indoors you're OK.

Comment: @J Stange its in the garage, the garage circuits are brand new, i installed myself (says the IT guy). I will troubleshoot them one by one with 50A feed to garage turned off.

Comment: @SeanS This is why I suggested you test neutral/ground isolation at each step when reconnecting your circuits to the panel.  At one point you had 300ohms between the neutral and your ground rod - with your circuits connected you don't.  One of the circuits you added back to the panel must be doing this.  If you check them one by one it should be pretty easy.  The other way to do it is to take all the grounds and neutrals off of the panel again and go around to all the outlets and test them for neutral/ground isolation.  One of the circuits will have them connected.

Comment: See above for recent updates to @J comments/suggestions. He was correct.

Comment: Glad you stayed on it and found the miswired outlet!

Answer (score 9):

The feed for your sub panel comes from your main panel the grounded conductor neutral and grounding conductor equipment ground are connected in the main panel so measuring continuity in a sub is normal even when the grounded conductor is isolated from the box and the grounding conductor.
This is normal the resistance value is usually quite low just a couple of ohms or close to zero. The length of wires and any resistance at the connections is all there is.

Comment: Correct, I measured 0.01 ohm between sub-panel neutral bus and ground bus then the same - 0.01 ohm between neutral bus and panel box. Do you see the dropbox link i posted earlier of the inside of subpanel? Remember no ground tie between panels, only dedicated ground rod tied to  subpanel ground bus.  Does that match your description of connectivity above? So it's normal?

Comment: Not only normal but required in the main. I have installed hundreds of panels that green bonding screw you did not use in the sub is required in the main or a jumper that ties both buss bars together.  I had a customer tear a sub apart when he found the same totally destroyed the panel trying to find the short that’s why I said pull the neutral in the sub and measure it so you did not start taking things apart. It is fine and you have very good connections.

Comment: Thanks Ed, You explained "measuring continuity in a sub is normal even when the grounded conductor is isolated from the box and the grounding conductor". I trust and will take your advice and leave things alone.

Comment: It's actually the resistance of the earth that is being measured.  The garage ground goes to a rod in the earth and the house ground comes from a rod or piping in the earth.  What you measure between the neutral (house ground) and the garage ground (ground rod) is the resistance of the earth between those two grounding points in the earth.  0.01 ohms is way too low for this to be the case.  Something is shorting the garage ground and the house ground or the 0.01 ohm was not measured correctly.

Comment: @j... I hate to say this but did you not read my answer. I actually explained the connection. No earth connection will provide a low resistance path. Please read up a little and not show your complete ignorance of electrical bonding and grounding. Special meters are required to measure earth because earth is a horrible Conductor! I actually have one of these meters but by your comment you have never seen one or made an earth measurement.

Comment: @EdBeal I don't think you understand what OP has described in their panel. At the garage there is a rod in the dirt and all grounds at the garage tie to this rod in the dirt. At the house is a neutral, tied to a different ground in the house. There is no ground wire between the house and the garage. Measuring resistance between the neutral in the garage and the ground system in the garage is measuring the resistance between the dirt at the house where the ground is bonded to neutral and the dirt at the garage where the rod is stuck in the ground. This can't be 0.01 ohms, even on a cheap meter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the original feeder ground IS connected (well touching)[see the pic] the case and providing a ground path for the grounds back to the main panel where ground and neutral are bonded together (Ed's comment).    This is certainly not a reliable feeder ground tie in; but maybe you can pull a bit of the wire to get more working wire and nut it to another longer wire and attach it to the ground leg of the box? Im not sure where the conduit with just a single bare copper wire on the right goes,  is that out to the 8'copper earth ground? (but its not relevant to this discussion). [image]

Comment: It's not touching - [look closer](https://uc4ddf31966508ea89f80541c758.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/AA4Hi_WDTxwweM03EGB8TxkFLSXYbU-B_2-dvUsGq5z7JmBzib4JOV0vmji_Vamav28w89bp0trGYjIBaBVTy1p2MlBLf-xwCQKvJb0MTSTECcHkVGksc_DuejavIH4URSKclSrsYZJC6CjNQEm2JZewXUL_4idc3CCgYXvDURhpOVASznMiMtWoIhnljUaAu_7YQ6NPPA3RVsURylz58KLcfT6MjlgTrP7vDMfwOvi9M1ZfTuxKl_RnfAQFOho9VRVeqP-j90aADywI0cdFD5zNcyCa_-hMG-DqYup0jczCL9Dn876sWBKc2_2OEK_PesiR18hhF9AgWGeUpKwxxU6rjaYuhCDTl0d0pGZfwsnpsHCR_QpHYItKKgM0Jpb_ApZ2P_bwCtUvUtsIv5UHVnkE/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5).  It's not even close.

Comment: The #8 ground does go to the ground rod outside.  It's connected to the ground bar which does have the green bonding screw inserted, so the ground rod is connected to the ground bar and to the chassis (via the green screw and also the AC flex and incidental contact).  The ground in the conduit is also clipped at the house (not connected to the inside panel).

Comment: Ok,  so to get Ed's "normal" condition where the sub panel's ground and sub panels neutral reference each other at <1ohm, there must be something tied together in one of the circuits attached. like a dryer plug with the neutral and ground tied...? or some other miswired plug. (pulling breakers wont id this, OP would have to pull plugs form outlets)

Comment: Im continuing this thread even though the OP closed it based on Ed's answer because I think the OP may have an unsafe condition, masked because it gives a "normal" impedance measurement for a properly set up 4 wire feeder.   One of his Outlet Neutrals seems to be tied to ground.  (other wise in THIS configuration he should get >>10Ohm grd to neutral

Comment: Thanks for red flagging potential about mis-wiring. I am confident in Ed's answer but  . . .would it help to use my CT70 AC Circuit Circuit Analyzer this at all the main house outlets ti ID potential miswire?

Comment: My concern (and Ed's if that cut off bare copper really isnt providing a connection) is that SOMETHING is attaching your ground to your neutral, and it COULD be miswiring in one of the plug/outlets. The confusing part is that normally, this would be the desired condition where the bond tie at the house provides this path, but since you only have a 3 wire feeder with NO ground to the house, something else is tying them together.  See @Js idea to disconnect each neutral from the bus, and measure the box's neutral to ground impedance/resistance (WITH THE PANEL OFF)

Comment: I did take an AC circuit load tested to all outlets in the house. There were no rev polarity, none without ground. Only a few that had Vdrop more than 5% (but less than 7%). So I have an electrician coming Monday who is a troubleshooter (and a friend of mine who I used to work with in Construction). This is the Wild West here in California, I thought anything goes on High Voltage installs?!? J/K of course. Really want to determine what is causing that "leak" and creating the continuity. Really appreciate all the Pros on this Exchange, glad @J kept this open.